# Replace top view in NavigationStack

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

I have a fairly complex app that uses `NavigationStack` with several `navigationDestination`s. Things were working well until I got a request to have a button which replaces the current view with a new view.

Essentially, if I have `var route = NavigationPath()` with a couple of items on it, I want to do this:

```
route.removeLast()
route.append(newDestination)
```

Sounds easy. When I tested this with simple views it works fine, but in the app itself, the views have many things in them (e.g., `Button`s, `TextField`s, `Picker`s, etc).

Using the above `route.removeLast(); route.append(newDestination)` causes "nothing" to happen - the top view just remains visible. I suspect the complexity of the views is causing the problem, but I cannot simplify them.

So I introduced a delay using:

```
Task {
   try? await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(0.5))
   route.append(newDestination)
}
```

This works *most* of the time, but every so often it gets stuck.

I need a sure-fire way to replace the top view on a `NavigationStack` with another view. Any thoughts?

Each "page" or "screen" is built from a JSON description from our server. So the destination will be the same view with JSON data that provides the blueprint for views in that destination view.

Comment: Just my thought, I doubt that the complexity of the views is the reason for your issue. I suspect 
it is more to do with the passing of the data to those views. Look at whether all the data are "ready" 
when the `newDestination` view is displayed.

Comment: My guess is that you likely have multiple routes

Comment: I have several `navigationDestination(for:)` and a single `NavigationStack` and one instance of my model which is passed from the `ContentView` via `environmentObject`

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with the delay after removing the last element before appending the new element. This works 90% or more of the time. My UI is generated from JSON and while its been optimized, it can be quite complex.

If you are running into a similar issue with `NavigationStack` I suggest adding this small delay to give the UI time to catch up.